# Adding more activities to an installed app

Tags: android

I am working on a mathematical exercises app. This app includes a bundle of exercises, but I would like to add more after the app is installed. How can I do that?

Comment: In short, you can't. It is impossible to edit an app after installation, unless you are an expert in `smali`. Even then, adding a new activity is nearly impossible.

Comment: Unless you did not program your app to be smart and reconfigure an existing "general purpose activity" to react to different database entries.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. It is impossible to edit an app after installation. if you try to add at run time or dynamically you can't instantiate an Activity if it's not in the Manifest, so you can't create one dynamically.

Comment: What you **can do**, though, is to create a "general purpose" Activity (or Fragment) which can be reconfigured by the mean of some value. I.e.: it could hide or show some Views if you pass it a value of 24. Or Show/hide some others when you pass it a value of 12. Just to say.

Comment: sir i said that we can't create activity/fragment after installation of application. sorry for my english.

Comment: Sir, you have to create it BEFORE installing it.

Comment: sir i agree with this.